# Javascript Using 2d Array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use this code to creating a count down timer from an html element.. however i don't want 2 timers to be running on the same element so i tried to create a `2D Array` that stores the setInterval functions and their corresponding elements so that i can clearInterval when another one is being set on the same element here is the code i tried but doesn't work (always returns -1)

```
function formatTime(seconds) {
    var h = Math.floor(seconds / 3600),
        m = Math.floor(seconds / 60) % 60,
        s = seconds % 60;
    if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
    if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
    if (s < 10) s = "0" + s;
    return h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}

var timers = new Array();
function timer(count, element) {
    var n = timers.indexOf(element);
    if (n > -1) {
        clearInterval(timers[n][1]);
    }

    timers.push([
        element, setInterval(function() {
            if (isNaN(count))
                return false;

            count--;
            if (count < 0) return clearInterval(interval);
            element.text(formatTime(count));
            return true;
        }, 1000)
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Your `timers.indexOf(element);` is trying to find the *element* in `timers`, which is an array of *arrays* not of elements.

Comment: Might be worth using an object instead: `timers = {};` and `timers[element.attr("id")]` or something.

Comment: Or even better, store the id of the timer in a data-attribute on the element itself. That way, you don't need to remove the element reference from your array when the timer has ended.

Comment: the easy way to keep one timer on an element is to use element._timer=setInterval(...) and clearInterval(element._timer); no ID passing or refs to go stale needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your timers array does not contain the element but an array of both the element and the setInterval function. As a result, timers.indexOf(element) will always return -1. Unless you are using jQuery or something similar, your elements need to have either an id or some other attribute with a unique value. Assuming they all have a unique id, you would have to replace your timer function with something like:

```
var timers = {};
function timer(count, element) {
    if(timer[element.id] != undefined) {
        clearInterval(timers[element.id]);
    }

    timers[element.id] = setInterval(function() {
        if (isNaN(count))
            return false;

        count--;
        if (count < 0) return clearInterval(interval);
        element.text(formatTime(count));
        return true;
    }, 1000);
}
```

assuming your element is a DOM element got with something like getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `indexOf`, you can search for the entry with a loop

```
function timer(count, element) {
    var match;
    for(var i = 0, l = timers.length; i < l;) {
        var entry = timers[i];
        if(entry.element === element) {
            timers.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    var entry = {
        element: element,
        timer: setInterval(function() {
            count--;
            if (isNaN(count) || count < 0) {
                var index = timers.indexOf(entry);
                if(index > -1) timers.splice(index, 1);
                return clearInterval(entry.timer);
            }
            element.text(formatTime(count));
            return true;
        }, 1000)
    };
    timers.push(entry);
}
```